# Loop Expression Engine Entries?

Tags: php, html, css, loops, expressionengine

I need some assistance with looping expression engine entries. I've hit a brick wall with a website i've been working on. Basically the site has 6 latest projects at the bottom with next and prev icons to the left and right. When you reach the end of the projects there is a back to start of projects button that brings the user back to the start of the projects... well, the client doesn't want this anymore and just wants the entries have an infinite loop!

Is this possible with EE, is there an add-on for looping entries I could use?

My code is:

```
{exp:channel:next_entry category_group="1" category="{categories}{category_id}|{/categories}"}
<a class="rightNav" href="{id_path='projects-test/view'}" style="color:#000;"><<</a>
{/exp:channel:next_entry}

{embed="projects-test/related" stop_before="{entry_date format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"}" category_id="{categories show_group="1" limit="1"}{category_id}{/categories}"}

{exp:channel:prev_entry category_group="1" category="{categories}{category_id}|{/categories}"}
<a class="leftNav" href="{id_path='projects-test/view'}" style="color:#000;">>></a>
{/exp:channel:prev_entry}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Related template code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="project" limit="6" category_group="1" stop_before="{embed:stop_before}" related_categories_mode="yes" custom_fields="yes"}
{if count == "1"}<ul id="filmStrip">{/if}
<li>
{exp:imgsizer:size src="{project_image}" height="68px" width="137px"}
<a href="{title_permalink='projects-test/view'}"><img src="{sized}" height="{height}" width="{width}" alt=""/></a>
{/exp:imgsizer:size}
<a href="{title_permalink='projects-test/view'}"><p class="thumbTitle">{title}</p></a>
</li>
{if count == total_results}</ul>{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Expression Engine doesn't often show up here, so response will be limited. Try over at http://expressionengine.com/forums/

Comment: Believe it or not, i've had a lot better help here in the past than I have on their forums. Their community isn't very helpful.

Comment: One of the drawbacks of a system that's as flexible and powerful as EE is that something that *sounds* simple like "looping entries" is actually quite tricky, as there's no one order of or limit on any list of entries. The ordering and length of any result can be vary so widely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This plugin](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/advanced-prev-next-entry) may do the trick for you.

Usage probably looks like this:

```
{exp:bbr_prevnext_entry current_entry_id="{entry_id}" category="{categories}{category_id}|{/categories}" channel_name="project" orderby="entry_date" sort="desc" return_fields="entry_id" cycle="yes"}   
    <a class="rightNav" href="/projects-test/view/{next_entry_id}" style="color:#000;"><<</a>
{/exp:bbr_prevnext_entry}

{embed="projects-test/related" stop_before="{entry_date format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"}" category_id="{categories show_group="1" limit="1"}{category_id}{/categories}"}

{exp:bbr_prevnext_entry current_entry_id="{entry_id}" category="{categories}{category_id}|{/categories}" channel_name="project" orderby="entry_date" sort="desc" return_fields="entry_id" cycle="yes"}   
    <a class="leftNav" href="/projects-test/view/{prev_entry_id}" style="color:#000;">>></a>
{/exp:bbr_prevnext_entry}
```

Comment: Hi, Gave it a try. It won't work because it requires a current_entry_id to be entered. Pretty pointless really, would be fine if it accepted {entry_id} but it throws back an error when I try this. It also doesn't support both "category=" and "category_group=" together...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you use `current_entry_id="{entry_id}"` (or `{embed:entry_id}` your case). And you never need to use both category and category_group, because category will always override category_group.

But regardless - looking at this again, this plugin doesn't suit your specific purpose. It's meant more for using **next entry** and **previous entry** links on a single entry page.

Comment: Actually, it should ... I added a code example for you in the answer.

Comment: Hi Derek, thanks alot for your help but its throwing back an error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND (ect.expiration_date = 0 OR ect.expiration_date > 1314090571) AND ect.ent' at line 1

Comment: Sorry, actually that was the wrong error, this is the error it's throwing back: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND ect.channel_id = 1 AND (ect.expiration_date = 0 OR ect.expiration_date > 1' at line 1

Comment: Using {embed:entry_id} gets rid of the error, but doesn't work. The urls are appearing as: projects-test/view/ then the syntax, eg. {prev_entry_id}

Comment: Tried numerous other things. I've also tried reinstalling the add-on. Nothing though...

Comment: John - this is a complex thing to implement, and meeting your exact requirements may call for a custom add-on. Email me if you're interested in hiring someone to write such an add-on for you - derek@amphibian.info.

Comment: Hello Derek, thanks a lot for your help. Client's budget isn't big enough to stretch for a custom add-on unfortunately so they'll have to just deal with what they've got, however I have taken your email address for future reference incase I do need a custom add-on.